# unable to open html file with Chinese character

Tags: encoding, utf-8, web-scraping, readfile, python-3.6

everyone, i run into a trouble when trying to open a HTML file containing Chinese characters, here is the code

```
#problem with chinese character
file =wget.download("http://nba.stats.qq.com/player/list.htm#teamId=1")
with open(file,encoding ='utf-8') as f:
    html = f.read()
    print(html)
```

However in the output I get error as follows

```
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 535: invalid continuation byte
```

I searched for a while , and i saw some similar issues, but the solutions seems to use latin-1, which is obvious not the case here, I'm not sure how which encoding to use?

any suggestions? thanks ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are referring to is not encoded in UTF-8 encoding, but in [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK). You can tell by looking at the header:

```
<meta charset="GBK">
```

If you specify `encoding='gbk'` it'll work.

On another note, I would opt for not using `wget` unless you have to, and instead going with [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) which comes with the Python Standard Library. It also saved the disk write, and the code is simpler:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://nba.stats.qq.com/player/list.htm") as file:
    html = file.read()
    print(html.decode('gbk'))
```

Comment: If this indeed answered your question properly, kindly please accept the answer.